# When redirect to SSRS report in .net core app, it asking for username and password in browser

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have requirement to redirect to SSRS report. I am able to redirect but it asking for username and password in browser.

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    var result = new RedirectResult("http://example.com/Reports/Report/RptMobile", true);
    result.UrlHelper = new UrlHelper(_accessor.ActionContext);

    result.UrlHelper
        .ActionContext
        .HttpContext              

    result.UrlHelper
        .ActionContext
        .HttpContext
        .Response.Headers.Add("username", new StringValues("username"));

    result.UrlHelper
        .ActionContext
        .HttpContext
        .Response.Headers.Add("password", new StringValues("password"));
        
    return result;
}
```

Looks like need to pass NetworkCredentials with it. But does't find any solution to do this. Could someone please suggest how to pass domain credentials in request.

```
var cread = new NetworkCredential(username, password, "http://example.com"),
```

Comment: You are getting the error due to SSRS authentication which get the users windows credentials automatically.  For code to work you need to add the user to the SSRS credential list.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/authentication-with-the-report-server?view=sql-server-ver16